# CSRF Token Generation for Rich Ajax application

Tags: java, ajax, struts-1, csrf-protection

My application is fetching the back end data using Ajax calls 90% of the times. I would need to implement CSRF prevention for all these calls. So i need to pass the tokens with each calls. Where do i generate the tokens? in client side or server side? if i create the tokens in JavaScript, how do i validate the same in java? Or is there any better way to do this?
I am using prototype js for Ajax calls and java struts 1.3 back end

I tried using the struts tokens, but it wont work since no forms associated with the struts actions.

Comment: in which format you'd pass the data between client and the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to [OWASP CSRF Reference](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) This will clarify all your doubts